# Mirror Modifier Texturing Painting Problem

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, mirror

I was Modeling a Low Poly Car using mirror Modifier. Sides of the car shares the same UV's. After texturing, a line appears to be in the middle of the model.

Question:
**How to remove that line ?**

[image: model with line down the middle]

Comment: Since strange lines are appearing and they are what you want to remove I would put that in the question to make the question clearer. It makes it easier for others who may have the same problem to see this is their question as well.

Comment: Try adding a bigger coloured margin around your UV islands

Answer (score 0):

Double geometry may cause this.

1. Select your object that has these strange lines in the outliner.
2. Go to edit mode.
3. Press 'a', to select the entire object.
4. Press 'w', to bring up the pop-up menu.
5. Choose 'remove doubles' from the menu.

If it's duplicate geometry, this will solve your problem.

Comment: There are no double vertice. "Line does not appear in Texture Paint Mode.   It appears in Object Mode.". Thanku